# If $\alpha$ is a Pisot number, is $\alpha_i^k$ a conjugate of $\alpha^k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha>1$. $\alpha$ is a Pisot number of degree $d$ if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer of degree $d$ and all its conjugates $\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_d$ other than $\alpha$ all have modulus less than 1.

Wikipedia claims that if $\alpha$ is a pisot number and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\alpha^k$ is also Pisot. My question is, how to show this? Will it imply that the conjugates of $\alpha^k$ are $\alpha_i^k$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the conjugates of $\alpha^k$ are the $\alpha_i^k$. The conjugates of $\alpha$ are its images under the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/ \mathbb Q)$. (Or under $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)$ for any Galois extension $L/\mathbb Q$ containing $\alpha$.) If $\sigma$ is a field automorphism, $\sigma(\alpha^k) = \sigma(\alpha)^k$.